# Node.js Express Web App works in localhost but not when published to Azure

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure, express

I've created a Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 Application in Visual Studio, which works fine locally. But if I publish it to Azure, the web page just displays a generic 500 error. How do I find out what's going on? Presumably the deployed App is missing something? This test is pretty much default out of the box, as a proof-of-concept exercise. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Really hard to help you without any code related to your issue. A 500 code error has something to do with your server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Can I get more context on this? are you publishing it to an Azure Web app? or hosting it on an Azure VM?
If it's a web app? what OS are you using Windows or Linux? I had issues where my node.js app works on Windows, but doesn't work on Linux.
Also if you are looking to debug a web app, do the following :

1. Go to your web app in Azure
2. On the left menu, under the Development Tools section, select either

   a. Console (This opens the cmd at the site root D:\home\site\wwwroot\ dir for you to debug and validate your files are there)

   b. Advanced Tools (This is more comprehensive and is a UI showing all your files etc. You can also select the cmd by clicking on the "Debug Console" top menu)

[Web apa Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s491g.png)

[Web app Advanced Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Lrg.png)

[Kudu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMDS3.png)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rimaz; this is what I'm doing: I created an Azure Web App, .NET runtime stack. I created a "Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 Application", in Visual Studio, and published it - without modification - to Azure. It works fine in localhost, but  - per above - not when published. Also, sorry, I don't understand how to use console, in Azure to see console log; what am I missing?

Comment: Some progress: Found log: Mon Oct 05 2020 17:21:58 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    ...

Comment: More thoughts: some users reported similar problems down to version on node.js; locally, node --version yields 12.18.3; on the server (console), it yields 0.10.40 - is this not relevant?

Answer (score 0):

So I created a similar "Basic Azure Noge.js Express 4 Application" using Visual Studio, then published the project to Azure directly from VS. It looks to be working fine.
How did you publish your web app? is it through VS or CICD?
Also just compare your web app configs against mine (last pic at bottom). Might help you

Screenshots below for your reference :

[Create a Basic Azure Node.js Express App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufw3j.png)

[Run in on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqZvY.png)

[Right-click on Project and select "Publish"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWBMq.png)

[Select Azure App Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIX9p.png)

[Create new resource group & app service plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5sUQ.png)

[Add Web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CnkY.png)

[Running App on Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Pe4.png)

[Web App Configuration in Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxHVY.png)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the choice of Runtime Stack when creating the Web App in Azure, which I did in advance, rather than on the fly, while publishing; I should have chosen **Node** (V12).